# RDLC reports were working fine on local machine, but I was facing following error on server

Tags: asp.net, server, rdlc

When i Deploy application. The report showing following error when i convert to pdf. but fine working on local server..

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: would need the error details to help you. Can you enable the remote error visibility and share the details?